# React Js E.label sets undefined in array using select reac

Tags: reactjs

im a beginner.please help me to pass the selected value and name or label from drop down selection.
im'imported  'Select react

React Code

```
const [task,settask] = useState([]);
const handleEmpChange=(e) => {
    if(e.label){
      let a =e.label
      setAssigntaskD({...assigntaskD,['Employee'] : e.label });
      setAssigntaskD({...assigntaskD, ['EmployeeId'] : e.value });
      debugger;
    }
    else{
      setAssigntaskD({...assigntaskD,[e.target.value] : e.target.value });
      setAssigntaskD({...assigntaskD,[e.target.name] : e.target.name });
  }
}
#HTML#

<Form.Group as={Row} className="mb-3" id="LbUser">
        <Form.Label column sm="2">Employee</Form.Label>
          <Col sm="10" style={{width:'50%'}}>
            <Select value={selectedOptions} options={employeeD} onChange ={(selectedOptions)=>handleEmpChange(selectedOptions)} />
            <p align='left'>
                {errors.UserName && <span class="text-danger" style={{width:'50%'}}>{errors.UserName}</span>}
            </p>
          </Col>
 </Form.Group>
```

Comment: Where does `e` come from? (Also, please format the code using the formatting tools available and the "preview" box below the editor)

Comment: const handleEmpChange=(e) => {
    if(e.label){
      let a =e.label
      setAssigntaskD({...assigntaskD,['Employee'] : e.label });
      setAssigntaskD({...assigntaskD, ['EmployeeId'] : e.value });
      debugger;
    }
    else{
      setAssigntaskD({...assigntaskD,[e.target.value] : e.target.value });
      setAssigntaskD({...assigntaskD,[e.target.name] : e.target.name });
  }
}

Comment: Please include all relevant code in the questions itself, you can update it using the "Edit" button.

Comment: Can you give the code of the handleEmpChange function?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what happens in the handleEmpChange function, but normally you would send the event to the function like: (e) => handleEmpChange(e)

In the function:

setData(e.target.value)
and maybe get the label like: e.target.getAttribute('label')
or log the event for all of the option of the event var.